# How to find which warehouse a Snowflake Task is running against?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I can see the history of my task using:

```
select *
  from table(information_schema.task_history())
  where NAME = 'MY_TASK'
  order by scheduled_time;
```

But this specific task failed because of:

```
Statement reached its statement or warehouse timeout of 3,600 second(s) and was canceled.
```

So I issued the following command to increase the timeout of the warehouse I think it's running against:

```
ALTER WAREHOUSE "MY_WAREHOUSE" SET STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 18000
```

But the task still gets the same error. How can I conclusively identify the warehouse I need to issue this command?

Comment: It's also possible that it isn't the warehouse timeout.  statement_timeout_in_seconds can also be set at an account, user, or session level.  In this case, the user and session likely wouldn't apply since its a task, but the account parameter would. 
 https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#statement-timeout-in-seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your task to use a specific warehouse, you can define it when creating the task using the WAREHOUSE parameter,
otherwise it will be serverless task and you can only define the USER_TASK_MANAGED_INITIAL_WAREHOUSE_SIZE parameter.

If you have problems with TIMEOUT on task, change the default value of the **USER_TASK_TIMEOUT_MS** parameter, by default it is 3600 seconds.

If you already have a task, you can change this parameter using the ALTER command, for example change to 4 hours:

```
ALTER TASK IF EXISTS mytask
SET USER_TASK_TIMEOUT_MS = 14400000;
```

Reference: [CREATE TASK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html#create-task), [ALTER TASK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-task.html#alter-task)

Remember that the task_history () function is very limited, by default it only returns 100 rows and only stores data for 7 days.
It's much better to use the TASK_HISTORY view.

Reference: [task_history ()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/task_history.html#task-history) function, [TASK_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/task_history.html#task-history-view) view

Comment: Thanks, can you include the exact command to change the user task timeout ms?

Comment: Here you go, added.

Comment: That gets me the following error: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 21 unexpected ''MY_TASK''. I used ALTER TASK IF EXISTS 'MY_TASK'
SET USER_TASK_TIMEOUT_MS = 18000;. This is task name corresponds to the exact task name in SHOW TASKS. Can you help me resolve the syntax error?

Comment: Try without the quotes and remember that you enter the value in milliseconds.

Comment: Ah yes, without quotes had another error but I should have read it closer "Unable to update graph with root task MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TAWSK since that root task is not suspended." So it seems there's another suspend task required in tandem with the one you listed if you can provide that.

Comment: Use the SHOW TASKS command to find them all and check dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Try running SHOW TASKS
[SHOW TASKS documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-tasks.html)

Comment: Ok so both Mike Walton and NickW are right so far. I used SHOW TASKS to find I ran the right set timeout task on the right warehouse and it still timed out after that at 3,600. So I just used this statement "ALTER ACCOUNT SET STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 18000" and hope it will work. Are the only things that govern a task timeout warehouse + account timeout? Are user and session still needed and default also to 3,600s and govern tasks?